# Compass config.rb need path based on scss file for sprite_load_path images_dir

Tags: sass, relative-path, compass-sass

I have a folder hierarchy like this...

```
- html
    - clients
        - client1
            - css
            - preprocess
                - images
            -img
        - client2
            - css
            - preprocess
                - images
            -img
```

My config.rb file at the moment is set up with these settings...

```
project_path = '/'
css_dir = 'css'
sass_dir = 'css'
images_dir = './clients/client1/challenge/img'
sprite_load_path = './clients/client1/challenge/preprocess/images'
relative_assets = true
```

What I am needing is a way to get images_dir and sprite_load_path to be relative to the ./clients/client1/css/*.scss file, not the root of the web directory. Is there a command using something like __FILE__ that can be prepended to these paths that points to the file being saved. I know that __FILE__ refers to the config.rb file so that's not going to work. What I need is something like this like this...

```
images_dir = <path to file being saved> + '/../img'
sprite_load_path = <path to file being saved> + '/../preprocess/images'
```

We need each client to be sandboxed like this because they are removed over time and each one can be unique from one another so changing folder hierarchy isn't an option.

Comment: Is it not reasonable for each client to have their own config.rb?

Comment: It's possible, but I would rather run compass from the root of the site rather than having to have a config.rb for every client and having to kick compass off in that specific folder. It just seems like there would be a way to find out the path of the file being saved.